# import from lib in python

Tags: python, importerror, vtt

I import vtt_to_srt converter.I read the instructions.I make the installation.From beginning to this "no problem" but when I import it as manuals describe python can't find the module there.
Installation

```
pip install vtt_to_srt3
```

Usage

```
from vtt_to_srt import vtt_to_srt
path = '/path/to/file.vtt'
vtt_to_srt(path)
```

Error

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'vtt_to_srt' from 'vtt_to_srt'
```

I am a rookie.Sorry for asking this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@SakuraFreak's answer was my immediate thought, too, but I ended up investigating this a bit further. It seems like `vtt_to_srt` stores all its API in the `__main__.py` file of the module. This file should normally be used when you want to a module using `python -m`.

This actually makes the module impossible to use the way that the documentation specifies. What I tried, then was:

```
from vtt_to_srt.__main__ import vtt_to_srt
print(vtt_to_srt)
```

This results in:

```
<function vtt_to_srt at 0x000002A0948216A8>
```

So it seems like this workaround is OK.

I do not know if storing all the module's code in `__main__.py` is some convention not supported by my version of Python (CPython 3.7.3 on Windows), or if it simply an error. Maybe you should approach the module's owners with this.

Comment: Thank you for helping.It is solved by you!As you mention I will inform the module's owner.

Comment: If the answer works, you should accept it (to signify to other users that this is a good solution).

Answer (score 0):

Because you're trying to import a function from the module which doesn't exist.

the correct way for this module is:

```
import vtt_to_srt
```

Comment: When I just import vtt_to_srt,it gives module cannot callable error.